# Chrome extension mouse wheel event

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

How can i handle mouse wheel event in javascript, part of chrome extension.

```
// MAIN
if (document.addEventListener) {
    document.addEventListener("mousewheel", wheelHandler, false);
} else {
}
// END MAIN

function wheelHandler(e) {
    alert("activated");
}
```

Activated alert newer happens, why is that?

Comment: It works for me, using chrome 22.0.1229.79 m (Windows)

Comment: Updated to 22.0.1229.79 (Linux) still doesn't work. What manifest are you using?

Comment: What do you mean with 'manifest'? I use the 'default' win32 installation and a few plugins (namely "Image Cropper", "CSSViewer", "colorPicker", "Resize Window", "jsshell" and "MonitorTab"), but I don't think, they're related to this in any way...
I also tested it on an older linux VM (openSUSE 11.4, Google Chrome 16.0.912.77), and it still works there. Are you sure, your mousewheel events are mapped correctly? What does `xev` show, if you're moving the scroll wheel? It should be mapped to ButtonPress/ButtonRelease for buttons 4 (up) and 5 (down).

Comment: Manifest like in chrome extensions manifest, you have to have a manifest.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't notice the 'chrome extension' part - I just tested the JS part in a "normal" webpage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome extensions require a manifest.json file which has the content settings for the extension. In this file you are able to identify content scripts that are run with the extension.

As an example (the first 3 fields here are required):

```
{
    "name": "",
    "version": "",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "content_scripts":
    [{
        "matches": ["url patterns here...."]
        "js": ["jquery-1.8.3.js", "main.js"],
        "run_at": "document_idle"
    ]}, 
    .....
    .....
    "permissions":
    [
        "some permissions...."
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

+1 to @Chef Pharaoh.
Using his answer you can make your script working on all sites by adding manifest.json file with a following content:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Detect wheel event",
  "description": "This extension alerts on wheel event.",
  "version": "1.0",

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://*/*"],
      "js": ["main.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```